# force strip label width big enough to contain strip labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Any ideas (preferably elegant but brute force, other than simply making the plot region wider, is also welcome) for making the strip labels wide enough to contain the long label *without* wrapping labels in the following example? I don't see any options in `element_text` or `facet_wrap` for doing this ...

```
library(ggplot2)
dd <- expand.grid(x=1:3,
      f=c("lab","longer label","very very very long label"))
ggplot(dd,aes(x,x))+geom_point()+facet_wrap(~f)
ggsave("strips.png",height=3,width=3)
```

[image]

Comment: tis relative to plot region width and if you made the labels wider w/o increasing plot width then the panels would be "scrunched" width-wise to accommodate, no?

Comment: possibly.  If necessary I can work around this manually by increasing the width. But since most other grobs have fixed widths (and everything adjusts automatically), I thought it should be possible to take strip text width into account when computing the width of the panel ...

Comment: i cld likely write a post-processor of the `ggplot_build` object to do that but it's likely the plot panel areas wld get very thin

Comment: Hi, did you solve this?

Comment: not that I recall.